# Sum of Column until a value is reached

Tags: excel, vba

| T's | Product | RS | Value | 180000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/21-22/00064 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 1718 |  |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/23-24/04240 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 3550 |  |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/23-24/04241 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 2384 |  |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/23-24/04242 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 1600 |  |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/23-24/04956 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 4824 |  |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/23-24/04957 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 1600 |  |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/23-24/04958 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 2498 |  |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/23-24/04961 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 22439 |  |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/23-24/04962 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 7180 |  |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/23-24/05081 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 3450 |  |
| TT/21-22/079 | PROD/23-24/05082 | RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR | 3101 |  |

I am trying to write a VBA script to add the total in 4th column until total reaches less than or equal to E1, I want to select all rows until the total is less than or equal to required value.

I have a loop running to calculate sum of 4th column but it runs into error because the total will never reach near the required value.

The code runs fine when the value of E1 is less than totals of 4th column.

I know its simple, but I have tried to no avail.

```
Sub test()
    Dim TempReq As Long
    Set sht = Worksheets("TempReq")
    lrD = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row

    For i = 1 To lrD
        j = 1
        TempReq = TempReq + sht.Cells(i, 4).Value
        If TempReq => sht.Cells(j, 5).Value Then
            Set rng = sht.Range("a1:d" & i)
        End If
    Next i
    rng.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: your code works fine, you just need to change the comparison sign around: `If TempReq => sht.Cells(j, 5).Value` should be `If TempReq <= sht.Cells(j, 5).Value`. Currently, the test keeps succeeding after you've reached the required value.

Comment: My apologies for moving your data around a bit, I'm not familiar enough with [Markup table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) yet to not have headers(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub test()
    Dim TempReq As Long, sht As Worksheet, lrD As Long
    Set sht = Worksheets("TempReq")
    lrD = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long, Rng As Range, maxValue As Long
    maxValue = sht.Range("E1").Value
    For i = 2 To lrD
        TempReq = TempReq + sht.Cells(i, 4).Value
        If TempReq > maxValue Then 'went over the limit
            Set Rng = sht.Range("A2:D" & i - 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If Rng Is Nothing Then 'didn't reach it
        Set Rng = sht.Range("A2:D" & i - 1)
        MsgBox "Maximum never reached"
    Else
        MsgBox "Maximum reached on row " & i - 1
    End If
    Rng.Select 'try not to use Select :)
End Sub
```

It notifies if the values were too small to reach the limit and where the last value  was at. You can of course use `Debug.Print` if you don't want to get a MsgBox.
Try [to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) since you don't need to use Select to use the range variable you have. Also, declare *all* your variables, use [Option Explicit](https://excelchamps.com/vba/option-explicit/) to avoid this further on.

Comment: Thank you @Notus_Panda for the solution, this works well for the logic I have been trying for a bigger problem. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! Just remember, I added headers but kept E1 as your maximum allowed value.

Comment: I see the changes you made to table.  I was just stuck at how to apply my logic because VBA is so object based and being a newbie I just didn't know how to.